# Can the left navbar be made collapsible?

Tags: support, user-interface, left-navigation

The new "Home, Questions, Tags, Users, Jobs ..." bar at the left takes up way too much space and is distracting. Can it be made collapsible?

I have always liked the way the site looked. It wasn't broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toggle the left sidebar into a minimal hamburger menu within your account settings. Go to your account > Settings > Site Settings Preferences and you'll see the following options:

[image: Hide left navigation]

Comment: It's still disappointing that it doesn't look great by default. How many users will the site lose because they're turned off by the look and aren't aware they can go turn this off? A little arrow to collapse it would be more intuitive.

Comment: @pvlkmrv: “How many users will the site lose?” → SO doesn’t care about users. It’s swimming in traffic and it doesn’t feel threatened by competition thanks to its special relationship with Google.